# Как поместить изображения в ячейку используя class?

Tags: ios, swift, классы, коллекции

Я использую **collectionView** внутри **collectionView** на **viewController'е**.
На данный момент у меня все получается загружать используя переменную с **типом string**, но мне нужно использовать эту переменную с типом **class'а** чтобы передать **массив** изображений который храниться в **class**. Я не могу понять как мне правильно подставить **class**. Просто так подставить его не получается, xCode начинает ругаться.

Мой код ниже.

**ViewController**:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var image: [Model] = []
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "Студии2")
        ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            var newImage: [Model] = []
            for imageSnap in snapshot.children {
                let imageObj = Model(snapshot: imageSnap as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                newImage.append(imageObj)
            }
            self.image = newImage
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        })
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return image.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell11
        cell.vc1 = self
        cell.imagess = [image[indexPath.item].image,
                        image[indexPath.item].image2] // изображение в созданную ранее ячейку
        return cell
    }
}
```

**collectionCell1**:

```
class CollectionViewCell11: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var imagess: [String] = []
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var vc1: ViewController?

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imagess.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell12
        cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imagess[indexPath.item])) // создается ячейка чтобы позже в нее поместить изображение
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if vc1 != nil {
            let vc2 = vc1!.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2") as! ViewController2
            vc2.photo = imagess
            let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
            backItem.title = ""
            vc1!.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
            vc1!.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc2, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

**collectionCell2**:

```
class CollectionViewCell12: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
}
```

**class Model**:

```
class Model {
    var image: String
    var image2: String
    var images: [String] = []
    var images2: [String] = []
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

    init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
        ref = snapshot.ref
        let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
        let snap = value["hall1"] as? NSDictionary
        let snap2 = value["hall2"] as? NSDictionary
        image = snap?["qwerty"] as? String ?? ""
        image2 = snap2?["qwerty"] as? String ?? ""
        if let post1 = snap as? [String: AnyObject] {
            for (_, value) in post1["images"] as! [String: AnyObject] {
                self.images.append(value as! String)
            }
        }
        if let post1 = snap2 as? [String: AnyObject] {
            for (_, value) in post1["images"] as! [String: AnyObject] {
                self.images2.append(value as! String)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В **collectionCell2** мне надо поменять тип **string** на **Model**, но при смене тип вылетает разного рода ошибки и нужно править код связанный с **cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imagess[indexPath.item]))** в **collectionCell1** или **cell.imagess = [image[indexPath.item].image, image[indexPath.item].image2]** в **viewController**.

Так же пытался вставить в **collectionCell2** изображения с помощью **didSet**, но все равно какая-то билеберда получается. Но я так понимаю основная загвоздка в правильности написании кода в методе **...cellForItemAt...**

Знающие люди помогите, я уже голову себе сломал... Не знаю как быть, хотя может и задачка то легкая.

Comment: Я советую имплементацию UICollectionViewDelegate и UICollectionViewDataSource выделить в отдельные классы (для каждого UICollectionView отдельно). Код сразу станет намного читабельнее и понятнее.

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk Спасибо за подсказку, этим займусь. Но сначала хотелось бы решить мою проблему...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну у вас тут несколько проблем:

1. Наименования. 
   а) Зачем Вы называете свойство `image` если переменная имеет тип Model в этом месте `var image: [Model]`? Логичнее назвать `models, modelsDataSource` и т.д. 
   б) Имя `ref` вообще ни о чем не говорит, если кто то в коде встретит такое имя о какой reference идет речь? Это URL? Какой то weak reference на другой объект? А если вам надо будет 2 ссылки на разные бд, другая будет `ref2`? Делайте имена более логичны и понятны, ничего страшного если оно будет длиннее 3х символов... `database, databaseReference, studioDatabase` это намного понятнее чем `ref`.
   в) Тоже самое и с самим `ViewController` и `CollectionViewCell11`. Если у Вас их будет 100, будете числа присваивать?
   *Как итог: старайтесь давать такие имена, чтобы по одному названию было понятно что эта переменная (объект, класс и т.д.) собой представляет, и что делает.*
2. Нет точного понятия паттерна MVC. 
   а) В `CollectionViewCell11` Вы делаете ссылку на Ваш же контроллер `ViewController`, это как минимум не соответствует MVC, как максимум у Вас будет утечка памяти, так как контроллер захватывается "стронг" ссылкой. 
   б) Вы зачем-то пихнули да еще и продублировали `UICollectionViewDelegate` + `UICollectionViewDataSource` в самой ячейке `CollectionViewCell11`! В итоге один DataSource у вас в контроллере, второй в ячейке, а обработка нажатия делает ячейка сама у себя внутри. Как минимум вынесите это все из "внутренностей" ячейки, в сам контроллер, но еще лучше как писали выше в комментариях - в отдельные классы.
   *Как итог: пересмотрите все что можно по паттерну MVC, что где и как надо использовать + не мешало подтянуть знания про ARC и тогда проблем с созданием в ячейке объекта контроллера не будет :)*
3. Ваша проблема:
   а) Для начала храните в вашем dataSource (который в данном случае image) не отдельные картинки, а саму `Model`
   б) сделайте в ячейке публичный метод `func setupCellUIWithModel(_ model: Model)` в котором обрабатывайте UI в зависимости от самой модели.
   в) в методе `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` или лучше в `func collectionView(UICollectionView, willDisplay: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt: IndexPath)`через indexPath "вытягивайте" из вашего dataSource определенный объект (который Model) и вызывайте свой `setupCellUIWithModel`. Вот Вы и передадите "класс", а точнее объект класса в свою ячейку.

Comment: За комментарии спасибо)) Буду исправляться и ошибки исправлю на которые вы указали. Я только начал программировать, поэтому еще не ко всему привык я пока делаю как могу. Проблему на самом деле решил уже, но еще раз спасибо на указание ошибок :)